# Syncing memcache and MySQL

Tags: mysql, caching, memcached, synchronization, zope

I have not come across a good suggestion on how to keep the database and memcache in sync.
I use MySQL 5.5.28, Zope 2.12.19 in my web application.

So, some of the suggestions are like once you do a select from memcache (during a cache hit), it sends the data from the cache. After this cache is invalidated and data is selected again from the database for the cache to be re-populated. But only because the database operations are expensive, we have opted to use cache in the first place. So how is this solving the problem of faster access ?

The other solution seems to be update memcache using triggers on the source table. Any inputs on this would be appreciated as I do not understand how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the links with the best solutions that I could find to the above questions.

The answer to my first question that mentions about the use of cache with rapidly changing data.
Well, caching is not ideal if the data changes frequently. This is true with less number of users.
But if the number of hits to the website increases, then caching is really useful when the following approach is used:

INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE operations will invoke triggers that would invalidate the cache.
And when the page is loaded, SELECT will be used and the resulting data will be stored in the cache until it is changed again. This way, the application's code does not have to be modified throughout the system by using triggers for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on the respective tables. Only SELECT needs to be handled in the code.

Regarding my second question on how to use triggers to manipulate cache, the link below has been extemely useful in answering my question:

http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/using-memcached-functions-for-mysql-an-automated-alternative-to-query-cache.